# Arduino Id Instance error on python vscde

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arduino, circuit

Whenever I try to run a code that is supposed to transmit a signal using **Sonar HC-SR04** module and then receive that signal to ouput the distance.
But as soon as I run the code, it stops immediately and this error pops up :

```
Opening all potential serial ports... COM3

Waiting 4 seconds(arduino_wait) for Arduino devices to reset...

Searching for an Arduino configured with an arduino_instance = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Hassaan\MarvinPythonTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    board = pymata4.Pymata4()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kk198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymata4\pymata4.py", line 235, in __init__
    self._find_arduino()
  File "C:\Users\kk198\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymata4\pymata4.py", line 404, in _find_arduino
    raise RuntimeError(f'arduino_instance_id does not match '
RuntimeError: arduino_instance_id does not match a value on the boards.
```

I've tried putting the port back, resetting the Arduino, fixing the code, (although the code works on the Arduino ide), updating the libraries, reinstalling `pymata4`, restarting my laptop, and changing the pins, but nothing has worked.

```
from pymata4 import pymata4
import time

board = pymata4.Pymata4()

# Define the pins
trig_pin = 8
echo_pin = 9

# Configure the pins
board.set_pin_mode(trig_pin, board.OUTPUT)
board.set_pin_mode(echo_pin, board.INPUT)

while True:
# Set the trigger pin HIGH
board.digital_write(trig_pin, 1)

# Wait for 10 microseconds
time.sleep(0.00001)

# Set the trigger pin LOW
board.digital_write(trig_pin, 0)

# Wait for the echo_pin to go HIGH
while board.digital_read(echo_pin) == 0:
    start_time = time.time()

# Wait for the echo_pin to go LOW
while board.digital_read(echo_pin) == 1:
    end_time = time.time()
    
# Calculate duration and distance
duration = end_time - start_time
distance = duration * 34300 / 2  # Using 34300 cm/s as the speed             of sound

print(f"Distance: {distance:.2f} cm")

# Wait for 1 second before the next loop
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Show us your minimally reproducible code, so we understand

Comment: I've added the code now*

Comment: FIXED, its because I had to reconfigure the Arduino to FirmataExpress, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reupload firmataezpress and it will work